# How to fix raised/angled toilet flange

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet, flange

My toilet had grout running all the way around it that was crumbling and gross so I took off the toilet and removed the grout but it turns out the grout was there because the toilet flange is about an inch above the floor and quite a bit off from level. The pipe coming up from the ground is 4" ABS and the flange (also ABS) is glued into it. It is 3" wide at the mouth and then opens to 3.5" for about 1.5" down into the pipe. I was planning to use a Dremel to cut the pipe below the existing flange and then install a new flange at the correct level. This wouldn't solve the level issue but I think a thick wax ring would make that a non-issue. Does this seem like a good solution? Another issue is that there is not a good way to secure the flange to the ground because the tile floor was cut quite a ways around. There are two joists on the front and the left that are about an inch away from the existing flange. Could I just put a screw into those at an angle?
Here are some photos of the situation.
[image: toilet flange at an angle]
[image: toilet flange from the side]
[image: toilet flange inside]

Comment: normally they are NOT glued in

Comment: Never in my life seen a non-glued plastic flange, and I seen a lot. Rough-in inspection here requres flange in place and pipe under test.

Comment: Could you use an internal pipe cutter to cut the flange off and slap a new one on?  Although if the flange is crooked, odds are the pipe is too, so IDK.  But the existing flange seems kinda high.